# How to solving Markov Chain problem in R?

Tags: r

I want to solve this problem using R for my Computer Programming class;

''There are 100 people in a room. Everyone has $100. Randomly everyone gives 1 dollar to another person. What will be the income distribution when this is repeated 1 million times?''

I know I should use a loop because it will be repeated a lot, but I couldn't find how to write the other parts.I am a beginner in R program.Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

dfdf <- data.frame(
  People = c(1:100),
  Money = rep(100,100)
)

for (i in 1:1000000){
  index <- which(dfdf$Money>0)
  index_2 <-sample(index, length(index)/2)
  dfdf[index_2, 2] <- dfdf[index_2, 2] - 1
  dfdf[-index_2, 2] <- dfdf[-index_2, 2] + 1
}

hist(dfdf$Money)
```

Is this work for your study ?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be simulating what OP described (though OP isn't clear about some details). It also seems to be buggy. If you put `print(sum(dfdf$Money))` both before and after the main loop, it prints a different number. (Just what is printed is random, but if you use `set.seed(42)` at the top of your code, you will see that the `10000` you start with mysteriously grows to `103666`)

Comment: The bug puzzled me, but it is traceable to how your code works when `length(index)` is an odd number. In that case, you increase `ceil(length(index)/2)` by 1 and decrease `floor(length(index)/2)` by 1. The population as a whole gains a dollar. The entire scenario your code seems to be trying to do is where one half of the moneyed people give one dollar to the other half of the moneyed people. This removes bankrupt people from being targets and also prevents one person from being the recipient of multiple dollars in one round. I don't see anything in the problem statement that leads to that.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes you are right. I created a scenario. Because, on the assumptions of the question, while people randomly give money to each other, there is no situation about what they will do after their money is gone. That's why I'm not arguing that my solution is the definitive answer to the question. just one perspective. About the buggy, i tried with your codes but i didnt get other than 10000.  Could you help me with that?  Thanks for feedback.

Comment: When I simply copy your code and put the line `print(sum(dfdf$Money))` immediately before the line `hist(dfdf$Money)`, it prints something different than `10000`. Your code breaks the population of the non-bankrupt into 2, increasing half by 1 and decreasing the other half by 1. That is unbalanced when the number of the non-bankrupt is an odd number.

Comment: Yes. When it is more than 1288, the loop returns a different result than 10000. I wonder if it would be a better solution if we first take 1 dollar from everyone and then randomly distribute it for the solution? (this time, the meaninglessness of can one give to himself is revealed) What do you think? I'm a student, different perspectives help me develop so thanks.